# Tortoise SVN suddenly unable to connect to repository on network drive

Tags: svn, samba

I have an SVN repository on a NAS, which is connected to my computer as network drive.
(I know, that's generally a bad idea, but since I'm the only one using SVN, that not such a problem.)

Right now, I can't work with the repository on my PC any more:

- When I try to commit / update a file, I get an error like
  `'file:///P:/ath/to/my/repo/db/transactions/123-3o.txn': The directory name is invalid.`
  Or similar, I'm not using an english version. This directory *does exist!*
- I can copy the entire repository from NAS to my local disk, and then update/commit/checkout that local repository
- I can create a new repo on the net drive, but when checking it out, I get
  `'file:///P:/ath/to/my/repo': Unable to open repository.`
- I have no problems with SVN servers, just repos on a net drive.
- There is another PC, which works perfectly with the repo, and the new ones I create with my PC.
- My co-worker at Redmont regularly installs new stuff on my Win10 machine remotely without asking me. This often leads to some trouble like broken programms, but he doesn't care.
- The other PC has no internet connection

It is clear that the problem is the repository being located on a network drive, and something on my PC.

Any idea?

---

**EDIT:**

- Doing a checkout on the command line, i.e.
  `svn co file:///P:/ath/to/my/repo`
  works fine on my machine.
- The path was copied from tortoiseSVNs error message.
- TortoiseSVN is not able to work on this fresh checkout
- Copying the successfully used repo path from the command line and pasing it into tortoiseSVNs checkout dialog results in the same error, again.

So, the command line svn (which comes with tortoiseSVN) works well, while tortoiseSVN does not.

Comment: So you say your repository is stored on the NAS. Are you using the correct path location in your checkout? I can't tell because your paths are just examples, but are you using the correct directory? Should be something like `svn co file://networkname/folder/my/repo`

Comment: @Chris: definitely. First, this just stopped working some day. Second, the invalid dir is like a link in tortoise, you can right click and visit it. Third, after creating a new repo, tortoise asks if you if you want to browse it. Fourth, tortoise allows to browse for a repo directory to checkout.